# How to search for element with attribute value as "\"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element inside my html with attribute "test" having value "\".
e.g.

```
<e1>
 <e2 test="\"></e2>
</e1>
```

Now when I do a find to get the element as follows:
    elem.find('[value="\"]')
I get following error:

```
error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value="\"]
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Read the documentation on special characters http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and there is no "value" attribute in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it says you need to add double slashes to escape a special character. But since \ by itself is an escape character, it needs to be doubled up. As a result, you need to have 4 slashes to match a single slash.

```
$('[test="\\\\"]')
```

And I mentioned in my comment, you have no attribute value, it is test. And the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) has a list of all the special characters in selectors that need to be escaped.

Comment: So, how can we generalize this for any attribute value ? e.g. lets say that attribute value is a user input and hence it can contain any special character along with normal characters as well. Now how can I generalize this approach to correctly search for an attribute value irrespective of whether it contains special character or not ?

Comment: Than you would have to write a function that will replace the special characters in the string with an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected by @Karl-André Gagnon: it should be `\\\\` and `test=`, not `value=`:

```
$('e1').find('[test="\\\\"]');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqqjn9e8/).

Comment: Should actually be quadruple : `'[test="\\\\"]'`

Comment: @Regent because the first `\ ` escape the second `\ `. When parsed into regexp, the escaped `\ ` will escape the `"`.